# How Do I get a More Specific Error on SSIS for each row

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

Currently I have a package that runs through several possible data flows. I have the failed rows being redirected to a log file and data table. That works great.

However, I'm not getting a very specific error per row. I have already changed the input method to "Openrowset" so it is going row by row.

The Error I get is

> "The data value violates integrity constraints."

My team needs to know what error occurs like the one below.

> "11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E2F  Description: "Violation of UNIQUE KEY 
>        constraint 'RAW_Primary_key_UK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 
>       'dbo.temp_table'. The duplicate key value is (xyz, 123, 123)."

I need this for every row, along with the data that connects with that row. I am trying an event handler. That doesn't allow me to get the data from the row that failed and it fails the component(and I need it to keep loading). It does however, get me the error message I am looking for.

It seems you can't set it to have both a redirect row and a event handler for errors.

So I am curious how to get the specific constraint error you violate and the data with it.

Again, not just the general "You violated a constraint".

Answer (score 0):

If you re-direct error rows you'll see 2 new columns - ErrorColumn + ErrorCode.

The error codes are static & downloadable - (All the standard ones are there)
The ErrorColumn relates to the lineage ID of the column in the data flow.

Note - If there are more than 1 error per row (eg 2 separate not null cols) - you only get the first 1.

This can be very useful in troubleshooting.

Comment: Thank you john mcTighe! I was sadly already doing that. In my companies previous process, they were using SQLloader and they wanted the same level of error specification. Using the method above, even when you convert the code, still only gives a generic error. I had to build a custom destination using a script component and catch the errors myself. SSIS pretty much throws away the original error....

Answer (score -1):

The error message is very clear that you are trying to insert duplicate rows into column which has unique constraint, that is the Primary key in temp_table in your case. So try to eliminate the duplicate values in your data source.

Update:

If you could not make sure the incoming data source, and whether there exists duplicate or not, add `Execute SQL Task`, and check whether the table has already had the data you are trying to insert by using `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table where...)`, and assign the `single row` result to a variable to control whether to proceed or not.

Comment: Long, thanks you for your response ! However, there are other constraints that can cause errors. Such as FK, actually that really is the only other error. I have all the "Not null" errors taken care of. The reason their are duplicates is because we have multiple data sources, that give us the same data. We take it, and then put it into raw->staging->then data warehouse tables. Through out the process we ensure no duplicates get in. However, we don't control where the data comes from.